# Vectors evolving by $\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}=\vec{U}(\vec{x})$: maximize effect of perturbation.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose we have a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ equipped
>   with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ which is given by $$\|\vec{x}\|^2 =
>  \vec{x}^TX\vec{x},$$ where $X$ is a matrix and $x\in V$ is in matrix
>   form. Further let us assume that vectors evolve in time $t$ according
>   to the equation $$\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial
>  t}=\vec{U}(\vec{x}).$$
>
> - Find general sufficient conditions on $X$ to ensure that $\|\cdot\|$    is a norm.
> - Consider small perturbations $\delta \vec{ y}$ from a particular    initial condition $\vec{y}(0)$. How would one calculate the $\delta   
>    \vec{y}(0)$ which evolves into the "largest" small perturbation $\delta \vec{y}(t)$ after 
>     a small time interval $t$? "Largest" here is taken to mean with
>     respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$ defined above. Further, how would one 
>     calculate the growth in the "size" of the perturbation? Hint: assume
>     that a linearization of (1) is appropriate.

First of all, I'm not sure if they mean $U$ is a matrix, or just a function from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$.

For the second part, do you think they're looking for us to perturb in the direction $d$ where $U(d)$ is the eigenvector of $X$ with the largest eigenvalue? How do we know there exists such a $d$? Or is there a way I'm not thinking of?